# Laravel error: "Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found"

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, xampp, laravel-5.5, easyphp

I need to update a website from a colleague to just add a LDAP connexion.

I use EasyPHP devserver 17.0 with php 7.1.3 and MySQL 5.7.17.

I've read a lot of docs etc to be started and to recover the site in local as it is working actually.

Everything was working so I began to add a login form etc... but when I tried to test a link from the website, it return me the error "Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found". So I began to search on forums I found some results about routes etc and everything I've tested didn't worked.

So, I decide to use the backup from the website as it was when I juste restore it in local(I precise link to other page and everything was working). I check the link and again, "Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found". I decide to try another developement tool and download XAMP, exactly same error. I tried with Wamp, Laragon always same error.

In the apache conf mod_rewrite is enabled.

My laravel framework version is: 5.5.39

So my folder look like:

[image: Laravel version 5.5.39]

The content of routes > web.php:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
})->name('welcome');

// Holidays
Route::get('/holidays/create', 'HolidayController@create')->name('holidays.create');
Route::post('/holidays', 'HolidayController@store')->name('holidays.store');
Route::get('/holidays/{holiday}/delete', 'HolidayController@destroy')->name('holidays.destroy');
Route::get('/holidays/{holiday}/edit', 'HolidayController@edit')->name('holidays.edit');
Route::post('/holidays/{holiday}', 'HolidayController@update')->name('holidays.update');

// Leave types
Route::get('/types/create', 'TypeController@create')->name('types.create');
Route::post('/types', 'TypeController@store')->name('types.store');
Route::get('/types/{type}/delete', 'TypeController@destroy')->name('types.destroy');
Route::get('/types/{type}/edit', 'TypeController@edit')->name('types.edit');
Route::post('/types/{type}', 'TypeController@update')->name('types.update');

// Users
Route::resource('users', 'UserController');
Route::get('/births', 'UserController@getAllBirths')->name('births');

// Leaves
Route::get('/calendar', 'LeaveController@index')->name('calendar');
Route::post('/leaves', 'LeaveController@store')->name('leaves.store');
Route::post('/leaves/{leave}', 'LeaveController@update')->name('leaves.update');
Route::get('/leaves/{leave}/delete', 'LeaveController@delete')->name('leaves.delete');
Route::get('/leaves', 'LeaveController@getAll')->name('leaves');

Route::get('/config', 'ConfigController@index')->name('config');

// Stats
Route::get('/statistics', 'StatsController@index')->name('stats.index');

Auth::routes();
```

My virtualHost in Httpd.conf is:

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1>
    DocumentRoot "C:/Users/sadm-m263733/Desktop/EasyPHP-Devserver-17/eds-www"
    ServerName 127.0.0.1
    <Directory "C:/Users/sadm-m263733/Desktop/EasyPHP-Devserver-17/eds-www">
        Options FollowSymLinks Indexes ExecCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from 127.0.0.1
        Deny from all
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I don't know what I could do but please ask me if you need more information to help me.

If it can help; gitLab link from the site I'm trying to restore: https://gitlab.com/balsigergil/btplan

Further precisions:
Auth routes is called twice, at first in the HomeControler.php:
class HomeController extends Controller

```
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    /**
     * Show the application dashboard.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return view('home');
    }
}
```

And then in the middleware RedirectIfAuthenticated.php :

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class RedirectIfAuthenticated
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @param  string|null  $guard
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
            return redirect('/home');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Do you think I need to delete this part from the HomeController :

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
}
```

And this part from the middleware:

```
if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
            return redirect('/home');
        }
```

I've delete the auth routes in Routes/web.php

Comment: Try `php artisan route:list` to see if your auth routes are correctly set. Also try a quick cache clear: `php artian cache:clear`

Comment: @SystemGlitch thank you for your answer, I've tried your command `route:list` and it returns all my routes without any error. Does it mean all my route's syntax are correct ? The `cach:clear` command didn't resolved my problem too (I've delete the cache from my browser too)

Comment: In the route listing, check if the login one is correctly set and points to the correct Controller method.

Comment: @SystemGlitch I got no authentification on my website so the login route is never used. Is it possible that not using the login route is the cause of my problem ?

Comment: You shouldn't create the auth routes then. (Remove `Auth::routes()`) and check that your controllers don't use the `auth` middleware, otherwise it would try to redirect to the login page.

Comment: @SystemGlitch The route Is called twice I'll post an answer to show it better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your VirutalHost DocumentRoot so the root is the `public` directory.

```
DocumentRoot "C:/Users/sadm-m263733/Desktop/EasyPHP-Devserver-17/eds-www/siteBTPlan/public"
```

Answer (score 0):

As you're not using authentication for you application, remove the `auth` middleware from your controller and this will be good.

```
$this->middleware('auth'); //Remove this line
```

Comment: I've removed the line, then `php artisan cache:clear` , clear my browser cache and I still got the same error

Comment: Does this line appear anywhere else?

Comment: In Routes/api.php: `Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});`

Comment: You can remove this line too but that will not fix the problem.

Comment: In app/Http/Controllers/Controller.php: `use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\AuthorizesRequests;`

Comment: But, If it's really a routes problem, why does the first time I've succeed to take back the site with all links and now that I'm trying again doing exactly the same steps as the first time it doesn't work anymore ?

Comment: Can you tell me which URL you are requesting and the exact response you get. Is it a redirect?

Comment: the link is in my navbar, I've got 3 links to 3 different pages. The link is done by `<a href"..."</a>` tag. But I've tried to manually write the link in the url for example: `http://localhost:8080/siteBTPlan/public/calendar` and it isn't working

Comment: Your virtual host DocumentRoot should be `siteBTPlan/public`.

Comment: Yes, my first and only page displayed without any error is `http://localhost:8080/siteBTPlan/public` . But in fact I don't know if it's important but the website actually in production but only in intranet have the main URL: `http://siteBTPlan` and to go to calendar page for example, the URL is `http://siteBTPlan/calendar`

Comment: It is important, the router can't properly work otherwise.

Comment: So, the website actually in production without the `public` in the URL isn't good ? The website URL in local is correct ? (`http://localhost:8080/siteBTPlan/public/calendar`)

Comment: No, `public` shouldn't appear in the URL because the DocumentRoot for the virtual host should be `siteBTPlan/public`. Check your Apache / Nginx configuration. Your site in production is good.

Comment: Okay, maybe It's just me writting the wrong URL to acceed my main website ? I've add my virtualHost config in httpd.conf In my post, could you check it please ?

Answer (score 0):

The root for Laravel is not the root of your Laravel folder. You need to setup your document root to the Laravel `public` folder.

```
DocumentRoot "<your-laravel-path>/public"
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but @systemGlitch already answered it 10 days ago !